# Facebook URL Scheme Suffix issues

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have 2 applications that are using same Facebook App Id. I am trying to use URL suffixes, and I have some issues.

I followed [this tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting#sharedappid) but with no luck...

1. I created suffixes on Facebook application page (I have "developer" role, not "administrator", but it allowed me to set suffixes)
2. I added suffix to iOS app .plist - fb123456789suffix
3. Suffix contains only small letters

As the result (using FBSDKLoginManager for login) I am getting FB opened in Safari, I can accept login request and then "Cannot open page" message.

When I enter "fb123456789suffix://" in Safari it launches my app

When I enter "fb123456789://" in Safari there is "cannot open page" message.

It looks like FB didn't update suffixes in application page, because if I will enter url in .plist without suffix (fb123456789) everything works.

Do you have any ideas or suggestions why this is not working?

PS. I am using latest FB SDK in iOS application.

EDIT: this is not duplicate. It was different issue, I was missing `FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix` parameter in .plist file,

Comment: @BootMaker actually I did try solution under that link, but when I try to use `FacebookAppID: 123456789suffix` I get error - no application under id 123456789suffix

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. The correct answer is adding FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix, which is missing from the screenshot in the Facebook documentation (and thus it is easy to miss), but it's mentioned above it in the text https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting

Comment: @Piotr Anyway to do the same in Android?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ok, seems to be solved.

I needed to add additional parameter in .plist:
`FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix` with `suffix` value. URL Scheme should be `fb123456789suffix` and `FacebookAppID: 123456789`.